# Splitting A Set Of Numbers Among Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game where I need to divide numbers 1-21 among the 7 players to divide the 21 cards among them, so each player gets 3 cards. I need it to be random, so I tried to make a function where for every number, it will add it to a random one of the 7 arrays, and if the array it was trying to add to already had three numbers (or in this case cards) then it would give that number to another card. Thank you in advance, David.

Comment: So what happened when you wrote that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a `List<int>` that contains 21 randomly shuffled numbers.

```
var numbers =  Enumerable.Range(1, 21);
var random = new Random();
var result = numbers.OrderBy(i => random.Next()).ToList();
```

Now, you can assign the first player the first three numbers, the second the next three, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I had to make some edits to work in unity, mainly that 'numbers' and 'result' are integers and 'random' is variable type Random. Also, I had to use System.Linq, which is not default for Unity, other than that this worked great (if this was obvious from the start, I'm sorry, I'm still new to C#). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, using the answer by adjan and Lestat, and the changing it into code that unity uses, here is the code I used. While I'm sure their code would work in standard C#, unity has it's own functions that don't always work with standard C#, so this is how I changed it. Feel free to use it.

```
private void divideAmong() {
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21};
    int[] result = numbers.OrderBy(i => Random.Range(0,22)).ToArray();

}
```

Note: You need to make sure you are using System.Linq